# How to resolve Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) openvpn

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I am following this [guide](https://averagelinuxuser.com/linux-vpn-server/#server-computer) to set up my own vpn server. But at the end, running the command: `sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/client/client.conf` give me this:

```
2022-05-11 15:18:13 Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in /etc/openvpn/client/client.conf:19: block-outside-dns (2.5.1)
2022-05-11 15:18:13 OpenVPN 2.5.1 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Mar 22 2022
2022-05-11 15:18:13 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021, LZO 2.10
2022-05-11 15:18:13 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
2022-05-11 15:18:13 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
2022-05-11 15:18:13 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
2022-05-11 15:18:13 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
2022-05-11 15:18:13 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]154.72.168.219:1194
2022-05-11 15:18:13 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
2022-05-11 15:18:13 UDP link local: (not bound)
2022-05-11 15:18:13 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]154.72.168.219:1194
2022-05-11 15:19:13 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
2022-05-11 15:19:13 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
2022-05-11 15:19:13 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
2022-05-11 15:19:13 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
```

The messages continue appearing but my attention is here: `Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in /etc/openvpn/client/client.conf:19: block-outside-dns (2.5.1)`
I think if a solve this it will be fine. Here is my conf file:

```
client
proto udp
explicit-exit-notify
remote 154.72.168.219 1194
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_OOQt9gddm6Urx1I9 name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-GCM
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIB2DCCAX2gAwIBAgIUaebTDbg0OAAvaZpKFVn4o8QQn08wCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIw
bla blaa
r8EfuIWxE43eAiEAqmivO3Pcxzi2Az3LCc1h2IUO//bx1BRgtD84feZuiIo=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIB3jCCAYSgAwIBAgIRAO6eGQVKtbv9C4zD2FVZPBswCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwHjEc
MBoGA1UEAwwTY25fQnhxTmdwTE
bla bla
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgEqd6QepY3nvgBD/J
fgvJWf/zVJwxhC8TVbA30ThP+yahRANCAARsASOeP+QTRFPq1utozH+8Cr4iUbhv
F5a1ABanAjO+T3FF1y+LDR7GW1Wr63GiZ/8Bq89koQ1UWrkbLT+gycf+
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-crypt>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
4b1dc16e4b3c65a48853222ce0ea2812
bla bla bla
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-crypt>
```

Comment: Please remove your ip address, certificates and keys from the question. After regenerate everything ;)

Comment: It is to résolve my problem or just a "security" advice ? Because there's no problem with the keys(i Can get other ones)

Answer (score 0):

I found this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946572/options-error-unrecognized-option-or-missing-parameters-in-push-options1#comment1505116_946572): So i edited my configuration file by commentting the line 19.
`# setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak #line_19`

My vpn is still not working but it not that error again.

New message:

```
022-05-11 15:56:17 OpenVPN 2.5.1 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Mar 22 2022
2022-05-11 15:56:17 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021, LZO 2.10
2022-05-11 15:56:17 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
2022-05-11 15:56:17 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
2022-05-11 15:56:17 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
2022-05-11 15:56:17 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
2022-05-11 15:56:17 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]154.72.168.219:1194
2022-05-11 15:56:17 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
2022-05-11 15:56:17 UDP link local: (not bound)
2022-05-11 15:56:17 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]154.72.168.219:1194
2022-05-11 15:57:17 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
2022-05-11 15:57:17 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```